# Individual desktop backgrounds in Task View

Tags: windows-10, virtual-desktop, task-view, virtual-desktop-manager

I am looking for a way to introduce per-task view desktop background in Windows 10. I have tried changing the background when viewing the individual task views, however, it seems to be that the background is changed globally.

Is there any setting / registry entry that would allow per-task view desktop wallpaper assignment?